# Invoke a function argument in scala

Tags: scala

In scala, I have seen some functions get another function as parameters. Can someone tell me how I can invoke that function.

If

```
function A needs a function as a parameter.
```

and

```
I pass B as an argument to function A.
```

Can someone please tell me then `how I can invoke, or use the B, inside A function`.

Comment: Please be more specific. Show one or two such functions that you want to invoke, as you might be misinterpreting what you are seeing.

Answer (score 4):

```
scala> def foo[A, R](func: A => R, arg: A): R = func(arg)
foo: [A, R](func: A => R, arg: A)R

scala> def bar(x: Int): Int = x + 1
bar: (x: Int)Int

scala> foo(bar, 42)
res1: Int = 43

scala> def nothing(x: Int): Unit = println("Yo: " + x)
nothing: (x: Int)Unit

scala> foo(nothing, 42)
Yo: 42
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Can you tell me how it works with when 1.the return type is Unit
2.the parameter type us Unit

Comment: @user3081714: `Unit` is a regular type in `scala` type system. It's a singleton. You should use `()` to get the only instance of `Unit`: `def foo(func: Unit => Unit): Unit = func(())`. Note that in this case you could just use a function without arguments (empty arguments list): `def foo(func: () => Unit): Unit = func()`.